# how can i fix FAQ page?

Tags: javascript, html, css

When I click on any of question the answer of all questions shown need to when I click on question1 show answer1 and question2 show question2 etc.... .

```
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.1.3.min.js">
</script>
<style>
    .prod{cursor: pointer;font-weight: bold;color:#06C;text-decoration: underline; margin:5px; clear:both;}
    .scor{display:none; padding-left:5px; color:#666; clear:both;}
</style>

<div class="prod" >
    Question1
</div>

<div class="scor" >
    Answers1
</div>

<div class="prod" >
    Question2
</div>

<div class="scor" >
    Answers2
</div>

<div class="prod" >
    Question3
</div>

<div class="scor" >
    Answers3
</div>
<script>
    $(document).ready(function(){
        $(".prod").click(function(){
            $(".scor").toggle("slow");
        });
    });
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

This shall solve your problem if the HTML is as it is:

Jsfiddle http://jsfiddle.net/ux9ump4d/

Script:

```
 $(".prod").click(function(e){
      $('.scor').hide('slow');
    $(e.currentTarget).next().toggle('slow');
  });
```